# How do I set the Test Run Title for an xunit test?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, devops, xunit

I have a .Net Core solution with several separate Test projects. Within VSTS I have a single .Net Core Test step. When this runs the tests I can see the results in the "Runs - Test Plans" section but each set of Tests is shown with "Run 1017 - VSTest Test Run release any cpu". Can I change the title for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Visual Studio Test" test task. It has 'Test run title' for setting test run title.